# Border with more then one child

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Border.

I have a TextBlock displayed on it:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
myBorder.Child = tb;
```

And it works fine.

The thing is: I also want to have CheckBox displayed on it.

The problem is that border is a single child element.

Is there any workaround here?

Thank you!

Comment: You can add a `StackPanel` or a `Grid` as the child element, and have as many elements as you want in them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The problem is that border is a single child element...

Correct, Border is a ContentControl and they, by design, can only contain 1 child.

> So... is there any workaround here?

Yes, just place a Grid, StackPanel or any other LayoutControl (Panel) inside the Border. This is a general approach that lets you create arbitrary complex content.

Comment: I already use `StackPanel` to store multiply Borders. Maybe there is a way to stack two Borders horizontally one next to each other?

Comment: Yes, in either a Grid or StackPanel with Orientation set. But do use a separate LayoutControl whenever needed.